# RPi 3 B SD Card not Working on RPi 3 B+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+

I just bought a RPi 3 B+ and thought I could easily plug in the SD Card from my RPi 3 B into the new one but the Pi does not boot up.
All I get is a blinking PWR LED.
I am using the official RPi Power Supply that made no Problem in the RPi 3 B.

I tried 2 different SDs.
One with Retro Pie and One with Kodi on it.
On the Retro Pie Version I did apt-get update and upgrade just before switching to RPi 3 B.

Comment: The new Pi requires the new updates version of Raspbian. Kodi claims support for the new Pi, but this also likely requires a new version.

Comment: Thank you. After some additional search i found out that right now there apparently only a Beta "Stretch" Version for Retro Pi. Didn't find anything for Kofi/Openelec